# shell script : how to merge 2 files asymmetrically

Tags: shell, merge

I have 2 files that I need to merge in order to create a report summary, as shown in the example below:

**file 1** contains workflow names:

```
Workflow_name.log
---------------------------------------------
workflow Wf_s_m_DAI_IFDS_Account_Stage
workflow Wf_s_m_DAI_IFDS_Txn_Map
```

**file 2** contains matching workflow-run summaries - that is, the nth summary block corresponds to the nth line in the names file:

```
*************** Summary ***************
Objects provided for validation: 10
Objects skipped: 7
Objects that were invalid before the validation: 0
Objects successfully validated: 3
Objects that are still invalid after the validation: 0
Validated objects that were Saved/Checked in: 0
Cannot save objects due to lock conflict: 0


*************** Summary ***************
Objects provided for validation: 14
Objects skipped: 11
Objects that were invalid before the validation: 0
Objects successfully validated: 3
Objects that are still invalid after the validation: 0
Validated objects that were Saved/Checked in: 0
Cannot save objects due to lock conflict: 0
validate completed successfully.
```

Expected output after merging the files:

```
workflow Wf_s_m_DAI_IFDS_Account_Stage
*************** Summary ***************
Objects provided for validation: 10
Objects skipped: 7
Objects that were invalid before the validation: 0
Objects successfully validated: 3
Objects that are still invalid after the validation: 0
Validated objects that were Saved/Checked in: 0
Cannot save objects due to lock conflict: 0

workflow Wf_s_m_DAI_IFDS_Txn_Map
*************** Summary ***************
Objects provided for validation: 14
Objects skipped: 11
Objects that were invalid before the validation: 0
Objects successfully validated: 3
Objects that are still invalid after the validation: 0
Validated objects that were Saved/Checked in: 0
Cannot save objects due to lock conflict: 0
validate completed successfully.
```

Please let me know the right approach to getting the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Ahshan

Comment: Thank You All, for your valuable suggestion, at this point of time , i'm all-set by solution provided by mklement0

Comment: Ahshan: A general tip, for both my benefit and that of future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it at least _helpful_, please upvote it by clicking the up-arrow icon. You probably received _downvotes_ because _you showed no effort to solve the problem yourself_ and simply asked that the solution be given to you. By contrast, the reason for _closing_ doesn't make sense to me, since the question is specific and has a straightforward, fairly short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` solution with `getline`:

Let's assume file `f1` contains the workflow names and `f2` the summaries:

```
awk -v namesFile=f1 '
  $0 == "*************** Summary ***************" {
    getline name < namesFile  # read next name from names file
    print name                # print name
  }
  1                           # print each input line
  ' f2
```

- The opening `{` must be on the SAME line as the pattern (`$0 == "..."`) in order for the block to be associated with it.
- `1` is (effectively) shorthand for `{print}`; i.e. it simply outputs the line.

Note that there's no error handling - the number of names is expected to match the number of summary blocks.